# Gamma of 3z using triplication formula:

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I have to demostrate the gamma function for 3z as you see below:
Using the multiplication formula demostrate gamma(3z)

> Gamma functions of argument $3z$ can be expressed using a triplication formula
>   $$\Gamma (3z)=(2 \pi)^{-1}3^{3z-1/2}\Gamma(z)\Gamma \left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Comment: I so if you demonstrated this what is the question?

Comment: i dont know hot to express gamma of (3z) like the right side of the formula

Comment: One way is start from the [definition of gamma function as an infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions)  $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = z e^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right) e^{-z/n}$$ and matching terms on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$(3n)!~=~\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k+3)~=~\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(3k+1)\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(3k+2)\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(3k+3)=$$

$$=~3^n\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(k+\frac13\bigg)\cdot3^n\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg(k+\frac23\bigg)\cdot3^n\cdot\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\big(k+1\big)~=$$

$$=~3^{3n}\cdot\frac{\big(n-2/3\big)!}{\big(1/3\big)!}\cdot\frac{\big(n-1/3\big)!}{\big(2/3\big)!}\cdot n!$$

Now use the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

Comment: This works for integers. How about real and complex?

Comment: @martycohen: That is for the OP to find out for himself, by subtly modifying the main idea presented in the hint. This is not a homework solving site.

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma(z)$ is log-convex (by the Bohr-Mollerup theorem), continuous and non-vanishing over $\mathbb{R}^+$.
By defining
$$ g(z)=\frac{\Gamma(3z)}{\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma\left(z+\tfrac{1}{3}\right)\,\Gamma\left(z+\tfrac{2}{3}\right)} $$
from the functional identity $\Gamma(s+1)=s\,\Gamma(s)$ we get
$$ \frac{g(z+1)}{g(z)} = \frac{(3z+2)(3z+1)3z}{z\left(z+\tfrac{1}{3}\right)\left(z+\tfrac{2}{3}\right)} = 27$$
hence $g(z)=C\cdot 3^{3z}$ for some constant $C$. From $\Gamma(s)\,\Gamma(1-s)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ we get:
$$ g(1)=\frac{2}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{4}{3}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{5}{3}\right)}=\frac{9}{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{2}{3}\right)}=\frac{9}{\pi}\,\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$$
and $C=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{3}}$, finishing the proof of the given identity over $\mathbb{R}^+$.